# Extracting correct type from a String in Java

Tags: java

I have a string input, and it can be an integer, decimal or a date.

How can I easily convert it to the correct data type?

Like, if its "7", then convert it to `Integer` representing 7. If it is a Date, then converting it to a `Date`, or if its "2.5567", then convert it to `Double` representing 2.5567.

Is there a library which I can use directly?

Comment: Get it always as a string, then parse it

Comment: No libraries, just write three classes with two methods each, Boolean accept(input) and T convert(String). T is the generic type here. Accept method will confirm if input can be converted to this type or not. And actual conversion is done via convert. Stack these using filter pattern. And you should be good.

Answer (score 1):

You dont need a library. Use the inbuild parse function of the type objects i.e. `Double.parseDouble(string)`. You can simply wrap that call in a try-catch block to try which one fits.